# ldap connection pool in web application

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, connection-pooling

I need to use ldap connection pooling in a web application. To authenticate admin, I am using below code:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize", "1");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug", "fine");

    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389/o=myldap");
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin,ou=system");//adminuser 
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "xxxxx");
    InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(props);
```

To lookup and authenticate another user, I need to change the SECURITY_PRINCIPAL and SECURITY_CREDENTIALS and then create a new context again. When I do this is a POJO, it uses connection pool but when I use this in multi user web application (I tried it with two threads), it does not use connection pool.

What workaround can be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parameters as JVM system parameters, using -D parameters on the java invocation.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize", "1");
System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug", "fine");
```

Wrong properties object. You should be setting those into the 'props' object, not the system properties object.

EDIT And don't debug to true. Setting it has has the curious effect of turning pooling off.

Comment: but when I use them in props object, the pooling doesnot seems to happen as even after setting maxsize as 1, I am create as many connection as I want but when I use them as System property then it doesnot creates another connection until I close old one.